# Padrão Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton

estou criando um projeto em C# e WPF, e preciso controlar instancias de janelas WPF, ou seja, se mando abrir uma janela em uma parte do código com `wndJanela.Show()`, quero que quando chamar outra vez o método Show() de outra parte do código, abra a mesma primeira janela. Para isso utilizei o padrão Singleton. Mas acontece que, quando chamo `wnsJanela.Close()` e tento novamente chamar o Show(), há um erro em tempo de execução com a seguinte mensagem:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: Não será possível definir Visibility nem chamar Show, ShowDialog ou WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle depois que uma Janela for fechada.

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
public static wndCadastroUsuario instance; //Campo publico estático que armazena a instancia da classe
    private wndCadastroUsuario() //Construtor privado
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static wndCadastroUsuario getInstance() //Método para obter a instancia
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new wndCadastroUsuario();
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Vi um exemplo de implementação do Pattern Singleton nesse link: `http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3397/singleton-padrao-de-projeto-com-microsoft-net-c-sharp.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

se você deseja reabrir a janela em algum momento, então não use o [`Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx), use o método [`Hide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide.aspx)